# Mouse settings won't stick?

Tags: windows-vista, mouse, reboot

I like to swap my mouse buttons (like a left-handed person) and use a slightly faster pointer speed than the default.

Why on Windows Vista Home Premium do I have to restore these settings again and again each time I reboot? Is there any way to make it permanent?

Comment: UPDATE: I did not find any option in setpoint to change the settings of buttons 1 and 2. For now I've worked around the problem by getting into the habit of 'Sleeping' the computer instead of shutting it down and rebooting every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually appears to have fixed itself. I suppose there must have been an automatic update that took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Logitech mouse? It seems it installs a program that resets these settings at startup - a violent crime.
Even after uninstalling the drivers, the program remains.
[This forum post](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-hardware-devices/10721-mouse-settings-revert-default-reboot.html) suggest you should remove a program called `Setpoint.exe` from startup, using `msconfig.exe` (type `msconfig` to the start menu run box, and uncheck `Setpoint.exe`)

Edit: Phoshi comments, quite correctly, that you can simply use SetPoint to configure your mouse.

Comment: Don't uninstall setpoint! It's really not that bad, and does add a fair amount of functionality to the mice. Just configure it in setpoint :P

Comment: Thanks. But setpoint doesn't give the option to configure the two primary/secondary buttons, only all the other buttons. Unless I'm missing something... how do you swap buttons in the setpoint settings utility?

Comment: UberOptions allows this.